# How to stop server in Client Server multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

I am implementing a multi-threaded client-server application in java. I want to implement **JDBC** in this program and I want my server to retrieve data from the database whenever it is started. I will store that data in my `collection` instances, perform manipulations on data and when server completes execution, I need to store the data back to the database. The problem is that the server is in an infinite loop waiting for clients and I am not able to figure out how to make the server stop.

This is my server program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // server is listening on port 5056
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5056);

        // running infinite loop for getting
        // client request
        while (true) 
        {
            Socket s = null;

            try {
                // socket object to receive incoming client requests
                s = ss.accept();

                System.out.println("A new client is connected : " + s);

                // obtaining input and out streams
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                System.out.println("Assigning new thread for this client");

                // create a new thread object
                Thread t = new ClientHandler(s, dis, dos);

                // Invoking the start() method
                t.start();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                s.close();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// ClientHandler class
class ClientHandler extends Thread 
{
    DateFormat fordate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    DateFormat fortime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    final DataInputStream dis;
    final DataOutputStream dos;
    final Socket s;


    // Constructor
    public ClientHandler(Socket s, DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos) 
    {
        this.s = s;
        this.dis = dis;
        this.dos = dos;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        String received;
        String toreturn;
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Ask user what he wants
                dos.writeUTF("What do you want?[Date | Time]..\n"+
                        "Type Exit to terminate connection.");

                // receive the answer from client
                received = dis.readUTF();

                if(received.equals("Exit"))
                { 
                    System.out.println("Client " + this.s + " sends exit...");
                    System.out.println("Closing this connection.");
                    this.s.close();
                    System.out.println("Connection closed");
                    break;
                }

                // creating Date object
                Date date = new Date();

                // write on output stream based on the
                // answer from the client
                switch (received) {         
                    case "Date" :
                        toreturn = fordate.format(date);
                        dos.writeUTF(toreturn);
                        break;

                    case "Time" :
                        toreturn = fortime.format(date);
                        dos.writeUTF(toreturn);
                        break;

                    default:
                        dos.writeUTF("Invalid input");
                        break;
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try
        {
            // closing resources
            this.dis.close();
            this.dos.close();            
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my client program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

// Client class
public class Client 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

            // getting localhost ip
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

            // establish the connection with server port 5056
            Socket s = new Socket(ip, 5056);

            // obtaining input and out streams
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            // the following loop performs the exchange of
            // information between client and client handler
            while (true) 
            {
                System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
                String tosend = scn.nextLine();
                dos.writeUTF(tosend);

                // If client sends exit,close this connection 
                // and then break from the while loop
                if(tosend.equals("Exit"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Closing this connection : " + s);
                    s.close();
                    System.out.println("Connection closed");
                    break;
                }

                // printing date or time as requested by client
                String received = dis.readUTF();
                System.out.println(received);
            }

            // closing resources
            scn.close();
            dis.close();
            dos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who has the capability to shut the server down in your design? Is it a client? Is it a special Client (i.e. admin client)? Or do you shut down on the server side?

Comment: @Impurity Its neither a client nor a special client. I shut down on the server side

Comment: Why is this tagged with JDBC? Except for you mentioning wanting to use JDBC, I see nothing in your question (nor your code) why this is actually relevant for your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It was added by Impurity in the edit. I hadn't included

Comment: @Impurity Why did you do that? You shouldn't change the scope or tagging from a question unless there is a clear reason, which here there wasn't.

Comment: But you did mention JDBC in your question, even though there seems to be no relation to JDBC apart from mentioning that.

Comment: I changed it as you deemed it relevant to include it and thus should be taken into consideration. Next time, rephrase question to include relevant information only then.

Answer (score 0):

**Overview**

Great question! To reiterate what was stated in the above comments, you are **looking for a server-side shutdown.** There are some way of handling this situation, and I can explain it with a brief example.

**ExecutorServer**

I will run through a modified example based off [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) example. Below find the server implementation.

```
class NetworkService implements Runnable {
    private final ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private final ExecutorService pool;
    private final AtomicBoolean shouldExit;

    public NetworkService(int port, int poolSize) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        shouldExit = new AtomicBoolean(false); // Thread-safe boolean
    }

    public void run() { // run the service
        try {

           // While we should not exit
           while(!shouldExit.get()) {
             try {
                 pool.execute(new ClientHandler(serverSocket.accept()));
             } catch (SocketException e) {
                 if(shouldExit.get()) break; // Poison pill has been delivered, lets stop
                 // Error handling
             }
           }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
           pool.shutdown();
        }

       // Clean up the thread pool
       shutdownAndAwaitTermination();
    }
}

class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    private final Socket socket;
    ClientHandler (Socket socket) { this.socket = socket; }
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
    ...
 }
```

Here you will modify your current Server code to intimidate this structure. You have a similar make up currently but here we have added `ExecutorService`.

> An Executor that provides methods to manage termination and methods that can produce a Future for tracking progress of one or more asynchronous tasks.

By dispatching your ClientHandler to an `ExecutorService`, you are utilizing a `ThreadPool`. Although this comes with plenty of benefits, the most significant ones are that you have more control over your multi-threaded service, the `ThreadPool` will manage thread utilization, and the application efficiency will increase tremendously.

Below is how you would attempt to shutdown and terminate all remaining threads:

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
    pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
    try {
        // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
        if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
            // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
        if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
        pool.shutdownNow();
        // Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Now, the question remains how do we shutdown the server? The above code shows a improved structure, but still have the issue of blocking on a `serverSocket.accept()`!

**Solution**

There are two ideas that come to mind when thinking of this scenario; a CLI or a GUI. Both have the same semantics, and the decision is ultimately up to you. For purposes of explaining, I will refer to a CLI approach.

**Poison Pill**

If you implement a `new Thread()` that handled all incoming commands from the CLI, this thread would act as a **poison pill**. The idea is to deliver a *poison pill* to the target such that can wake up/execute and die. The thread will change the `shouldExit` atomic boolean to `true` and create a `new Socket(serverSocket.getInetAddress(), serverSocket.getLocalPort()).close();` to connect to the `ServerSocket` and immediately close it. In the above code, the application will no longer be blocking on the `serverSocket.accept()`. Instead, it will enter the try catch for `SocketExceptions` and test if a poison pill was utilized; If it was then lets clean up, if not lets error handle.

**Timeout**

You could also set a timeout on the `ServerSocket` such that it will throw an exception each time it cannot get a connection in that time interval with `myServer.setSoTimeout(2000);`. This will throw an `InterruptedIOException` and can be handled similarly to the poison pill where the flag is changed via a CLI command and it checks if it should exit in the catch block. If it should exit, lets clean up, if not lets error handle.

Comment: `The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) AtomicBoolean` I get this error for shouldExit in the while loop

Comment: In my code I have a main method where I create instances of ClientHandler. NetworkServices class in your example implements Runnable. But to execute the Server, I need a main method. How do I write the main method?

Comment: @EdmundFitzgerald I fixed that error you were getting

Comment: @EdmundFitzgerald I keep your server class with the main in your src. Then, I would start running the NetworkService from there as well as setting up your GUI or CLI.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [pattern flag](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html) with volatile boolean variable, and you should place it in 'while' - when processing would be finished, turn it to false and the server would stop.

Another way - use [thread pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) and wait for them to finish in the main thread of your server.